# Can I add an SSHD drive to an HDD/SSD compatible device?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Can I add an SSHD drive to a laptop that according to its maintenance sheets, requires HDD or SATA drives to work? Screen shot is included of the document mentioned.
[image]

Comment: Provided the physical drive will fit, of course you can, all SSHD devices are SATA devices.  The problem you will find is that, the sizes your laptop supports, do not exist in 2015.

Comment: One frustration is the BIOS of the laptop may take a larger modern day drive and limit its size to what was common when the laptop was manufactured. I had this happen when I tried to replace a 250GB drive on a 7+ year old dell with a modern 1 TB 2.5 inch drive. The firmware used a SATA command to reduce the size of the drive to 250GB and lock it at this reduced size so that when I put the drive in a different PC it still showed up as 250GB (I eventually unlocked the drive to restore its size so I could use it on a different system but it was a pain).

Comment: I think that "supports" list lists the drives that you could purchase with the laptop. As long as the bios/firmware is any bit of recent and/or decent, it will support drives of arbitrary size. At least, it's supposed to. Of course it's still HP, with their custom bioses you may be out of luck. Why do you call it an SSHD though, are you thinking about purchasing a Hybrid drive or are you actually looking for an SSD?

Comment: @CodeCaster I am looking for a hybrid drive that is more affordable than SSD and still faster than typical HDD.

Comment: @drescherjm interesting story. That is too bad IMO to have BIOS lock a drive's size.

Comment: @JasonStack - It was more about the SATA controller then the firmware on a device.  Most SATA controllers around the date your laptop was new would have the same limitations.

Comment: You should be fine with using an SSHD, there is nothing different between an HDD ans SSHD as far as the PC is concerned. Just make sure to find a model that would be thin enough to fit into your laptop. Check the model of your current HDD to find its Height and look for one that is the same size or smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I believe there are some misconcepts in the question above.

1 - The DASD capacity limit happened when you try to add very new devices to a very old computers, as the BIOS doesn't recognize the larger HD's. It happenned to me when I bought a 40 MB disk, and our 80286 and DOS 1.0 addressed only 32MB. This limit has been changing and I believe, after 2GB dasd, the limit has increased so much, it probably will be the for some years from now.

2 - Either SSD and SSHD (some laptops now comes with both, HD and SSD HD) are seen by BIOS (I believe that's right) as a SATA HD. According to the article in http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/buying-advice/pc-upgrades/ssd-vs-sshd-solid-state-or-hybrid-3520515/ (PC Advisor page) the SSHD is an hybrid that has its own intelligence for using either part of it, and thus, your BIOS or OS would not need to consider this feature at all.

- That said, I would add this SSHD device without blinking. Unless your laptop is so old that HD bigger than 32G cannot be addressed.

Comment: The machine is a 2010 build, so according to your answer, no problem should occur relating to size limits.

Comment: I would not expect a size limit problem with a 2010 system.

Comment: Yes, last size limit occurred when HDs bigger than 32G appeared, and Windows had to change the file system from FAT32 to NTFS in order to address the new sizes. That's why we cannot format HD with FAT32  any more.